# Oracle - Monitoring tablespace warnings and critical events via Microsoft Windows Event log

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I would like to monitor tablespace warning and critical events of my Oracle database (12c Standard Release 12.2.0.1.0) via Microsoft Windows Event Viewer and attach tasks to it.

Right now only a few event log entries of the Oracle db are available in Event Viewer - i assume this is because `audit_trail` is currently set to `DB`.

Is it the correct way to set `audit_trail` to `OS` to get the desired events in Windows Event Viewer?

Anything i have to consider regarding this change?